# How to set content assist to insert only a single closed tag?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xhtml

I am using a lot of tags that can be closed right away, but Eclipse always puts a start- and an end tag.
Is there a simple way to change this standard behaviour?

If possible I would like to make exceptions for tags that really do not make sense to be closed immediately (e.g. a form tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install WTP or Eclipse for Java EE. In your Preferences, go to Web -> HTML Files -> Editor -> Typing

You should find what you need here, either in the "Automatically remove" section, "End tags when creating empty self-closing tags" checkbox, or in the "When typing an end tag" section, "Automatically close tag" checkbox.